# Authenticating webapp using Azure Managed Identity without access hosting environment

Tags: azure-web-app-service, .net-6.0, azure-api-management, azure-managed-identity

My expectation here is that this is impossible, but I figure I'd ask just to be sure.

Our setup is a bit unique. We have an Azure environment which will be hosting various resources, among which is API Management (APIM). We are looking to secure access to APIM using a Managed Identity (MI). We are also looking to connect to APIM through a .NET6 webapp.

The challenge is that this webapp will be deployed into a different environment that we have no control over, or access to.

Is there any way to use a MI in this scenario? From my understanding, the typical workflow is to use `DefaultAzureCredential` to access the MI (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/authentication?tabs=command-line#use-defaultazurecredential-in-an-application)), however, I believe that requires MI to be configured in the same environment the webapp is deployed to. Is there a way to authenticate against the MI using a "traditional" approach of a ClientID/ClientSecret, or is that essentially the exact thing that MI is trying to prevent?

Comment: Looks like you have to use the ClientID/Secret flow. [MI FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/managed-identities-faq#can-i-use-a-managed-identity-to-access-a-resource-in-a-different-directorytenant)

Comment: Is it same Azure AD ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a web app to use `MI`, we need to configure few things in `Azure App Service`.

We need to set the `Identity Provider` in the `Authentication`.

[image]

[image]

The above is possible only if the WebApp is deployed in the `Azure App Service` and the hosting environment is known.

AFAIK, we do not have a direct way to authenticate a web app using `Managed Identity` without the hosting Environment.

We can use Managed Identity when we build our application using Azure App Service, Azure Functions, Azure VM, AKS, Azure Container Instances, Azure Storage, Logic Apps.

> I believe that requires MI to be configured in the same environment the webapp is deployed to. Is there a way to authenticate against the MI using a "traditional" approach of a ClientID/ClientSecret,

One alternative way to achieve this is by registering the App in the `Azure Active Directory`.

- Navigate to the APIM instance in Azure Portal, if you don't have create a new APIM.
- Enable `Azure AD` from the `Portal overview` as shown below.

[image]

[image]

- Identities will be created with ClientID.

[image]

- New App with same name as `APIM` will be registered in the `AAD`.

[image]

- In APIM, add the new Group.I got the error as shown below.

[image]

- To add new `Azure AD Group`, we need to have `Directory.Read.All` permissions for `Azure Active Directory Graph`  in `AAD` => `API permissions`.

[image]

- We can also manually register the App in AAD.

Comment: Hey Harshitha, thanks for the detailed response! The second scenario seems like a traditional client secret approach, however, if I understand correctly, we wouldn't be able to use MI to authenticate against it. We'd need to use a standard OAuth2 authentication routine, using the clientID/clientsecret.

Comment: Yes,as you have mentioned we need to follow the OAuth2 Authentication.